# import Map from QGIS into QT Designer

Tags: qgis, qt, qt-designer

I am looking for a way to get a map from QGIS into QT Designer. I have the QT Designer version that comes with QGIS, meaning i have all the standard QGIS Widget. I don´t see a map widget, but many things belonging to a map e.g. a mapScaleWidget.

How can I get a few functions and a map into QT?

I can programm a little bit of python, but I have not yet made any plugins myself, because I personally think I can´t programm good enough for that yet.

I also do not know how to install plugins.

Comment: Why do you want to bring a map into QT Designer?

Comment: I want to make a programm where you can easily view maps from QGIS. Someone has to use this map, but they have no clue what QGIS is, so i want to make it easier for them to navigate in the map.

Comment: You might want to start with a bit of research. https://locatepress.com/ppg

Comment: I am sorry but i think you missunderstood. I do not have the time to learn a new programming language and i do not have the time to make my own widget. That´s why i wanted to ask if there was anything else to do. like an implemented solution.

Answer (score 2):

You mean QgsMapCanvas?

First place somwhere **QWidget**. Now right click on this widget and choose "promote" (or replace, I don't remember). Set **QgsMapCanvas** as class name and set **qgis.gui** as header file. And that's all, you have a map canvas, you can display layers in this wigdet.

Comment: What exaclty is a QWidget? I am sorry i am relatively new to this topic.

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/ECJa9CX.png

Comment: Thanks! When i enter your above mentioned things, I can not seem to hit apply for some reason. Why might that be the case?

Comment: Click "add" first, this class will be displayed in the table above, and than you can "apply".

Comment: now it worked, but it did not do anything. Is something supposed to change?

Comment: Now you can use this widget to display data. Check out for more tutorials: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! thanks so much! somehow i was not able to find this website.

Comment: one more thing. Do i still have to add that code from that manual, or can I either code, or do it in Qt Designer without writing any code? If i have to write code, where do i do that in Qt Designer?